# How to retrieve data from ArrayList<ModelObject> not from ArrayList<String>?

Tags: android, arraylist

Hi I'm still new to java data management.

I have a model object class named Computer which has 3 fields: processor, ram, hddSize.

I created a ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Computer> myCompList = new ArrayList<Computer>();

        Computer comp1 = new Computer();
        comp1.setProcessor("1.5 GHZ");
                    comp1.setRam("512 MB");
                    comp1.setHddSize("100 GB");

        Computer comp2 = new Computer();
        comp2.setProcessor("2.5 GHZ");
                    comp2.setRam("512 MB");
                    comp2.setHddSize("50 GB");

                    myCompList.add(comp1);
                    myCompList.add(comp2);
```

Now How can I retrieve data at index1 of the ArrayList above?

PS: I know how to do it if its a ArrayList< String> by convert it to String[] and then String[index].

Comment: To everyone jumping in to get free rep: Try to encourage good programming practice by pointing out the correct way to figure this out, instead of just giving the answer outright.

Comment: Sorry ppl, Im just too new to java/android environment. I'm coming from iOS. I did search for this but I could not find anyone. Anyway thanks for all your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Javadocs for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

This is where you should check for simple questions like this. The answer can be found in the "Method Summary" section.

Comment: I came here, but somehow I didn't see "get" method. Thank you for you help and comment above.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with Android!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have created getters and setters in your Computer class:

```
String processor = myCompList.get(1).getProcessor();
String ram = myCompList.get(1).getRam();
String hddSize = myCompList.get(1).getHddSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go `myCompList.get(0);` ?

An arraylist of objects is essentially the same as an arraylist of strings.  The `.get()` method returns the specific object at the given index.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is the documentation for ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

`myCompList.get(index)` will return you data on the given index, make sure index number wouldn't be greater than array size, it will give you index out of bounds exception.